# Freshly installed weblogic with rcu and soa crashing

Tags: java, exception, out-of-memory, weblogic, soa

My weblogic application server crashing at startup. Today I installed Oracle DB12c database, WEBLOGIC 10.3.6, RCU 11.1.1.6 and SOA generic 11. I created an empty weblogic soa domain, runned `setSOADomainEnv.cmd` than `startWeblogic.cmd` but weblogic throws me tons of warning and exceptions like :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Here is the part of the [log](https://pastebin.com/Uee9m5LE).
Some warnings [here](https://pastebin.com/PFV3ij31).

I reinstalled it all like 10 times with different JDKs 1.7, 1.6 etc, but still I got the same results.

I am using Windows 7 Professional.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try setting up the memory parameters for your JVM.
See: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2600343

Assuming your machine have enough RAM. Do the errors occur when you start the server or when you try to access a UI console (such as /em)?

Comment: I will try setting up the memory limit for my JVM higher. When I start the bank domain without soa features, only weblogic, it works without a problem.
Yeah, I have 16GB of RAM. These strange errors occur when I start the server.

Comment: Might be due to the way you are starting the servers and how you set up the domain.
Assuming you have a domain with one Admin Server and one SOA managed server, you don't need to call setSOADomain explicitly. 
You simply:
start the admin server first using the  startWebLogic script and then the start the managed server separately using the startManagedWeblogic .

(Eventually you can do this via the console once you set up node manager etc.)